# Why hashCode method affect performance of comparison?

Tags: java, performance, hashtable, equals

I've found the following code [here](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html). It is argued that "The programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables." Another questions are why 7 and 31 are selected on line 20, 21 and 22?

```
1.  public class Test
2.  {
3.      private int num;
4.      private String data;
5.
6.      public boolean equals(Object obj)
7.      {
8.          if(this == obj)
9.              return true;
10.         if((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
11.             return false;
12.         // object must be Test at this point
13.         Test test = (Test)obj;
14.         return num == test.num &&
15.         (data == test.data || (data != null && data.equals(test.data)));
16.     }
17.
18.     public int hashCode()
19.     {
20.         int hash = 7;
21.         hash = 31 * hash + num;
22.         hash = 31 * hash + (null == data ? 0 : data.hashCode());
23.         return hash;
24.     }
25.
26.     // other methods
27. }
```

Comment: @user2864740 that is irrelevant, the title of question is "Does MySQL index foreign key columns automatically?"

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468589/hashcode-bucket-distribution-in-java/11468648#11468648 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757363/java-hashmap-performance-optimization-alternative

Comment: And, in a shameless plug, http://powerfield-software.com/?p=615 :-)

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table